# Overwrite a module in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, extend, child-theming

I am modifying a module in a theme and adding it in the child theme. This module is not a page template  but is a PHP file. I placed the file in the same hierarchy in the child theme as in the parent theme but WordPress didnt pick the child theme file. How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Child themes are meant to override ***templates***. Templates are usually included with `get_template_part()` which is basically using the following function:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the name of the highest priority template file that exists.
 *
 * Searches in the STYLESHEETPATH before TEMPLATEPATH and wp-includes/theme-compat
 * so that themes which inherit from a parent theme can just overload one file.
 *
 * @since 2.7.0
 *
 * @param string|array $template_names Template file(s) to search for, in order.
 * @param bool         $load           If true the template file will be loaded if it is found.
 * @param bool         $require_once   Whether to require_once or require. Default true. Has no effect if $load is false.
 * @return string The template filename if one is located.
 */
function locate_template($template_names, $load = false, $require_once = true ) {
    $located = '';
    foreach ( (array) $template_names as $template_name ) {
        if ( !$template_name )
            continue;
        if ( file_exists(STYLESHEETPATH . '/' . $template_name)) {
            $located = STYLESHEETPATH . '/' . $template_name;
            break;
        } elseif ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $template_name) ) {
            $located = TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $template_name;
            break;
        } elseif ( file_exists( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/' . $template_name ) ) {
            $located = ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/' . $template_name;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( $load && '' != $located )
        load_template( $located, $require_once );

    return $located;
}
```

As you can see, `STYLESHEETPATH` (the child theme path) is checked prior to the template path. But you have to include the file like a template.

***It is not possible to override arbitrary PHP files with child themes. You also do not override the parents' functions.php, instead you extend it.***

What you can do to solve your problem:

1. Include new functionality PHP files with `require()` or `include()` in your child themes functions.php
2. Hook into your parent themes functions with `add_filter` or `add_action`
3. If all of this does not help, bother to parent theme developers to increase its extensibility